# When an IOException generally occur and what action should I take to properly handle it?

Tags: java, exception

I am using File Input/Output streams. I know that reading a non-existent file from program using `FileInputStream` will give `FileNotFoundException`. Right? So I can catch this excpetion and can return null or 0 value(depends on return type of my method performing all this reading operations) on Exception to convey the calling program that file does not exist and should create the one.

But I don't know when `IOException` generally occurs and what is the exact reason I should convey to calling program that 'this' has happened because of 'that'.
I exactly don't know what is 'this' and 'that' here.

Anybody please elaborate me in what cases does the `IOException` can occur and what specific action should I take in such case.
Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Because you executed an I/O operation but this results in an error. Example: you try to read an `int` but the application read a `String`.

Comment: *what specific action should I take in such case* it will depend on the action you're doing. There's no specific answer for that.

Comment: Every method of the java.io classes throwing an IOException is documented, and explains when and why an IOException is thrown. Read the javadoc. Moreover, returning 0 or null is usually not the right way to deal with an IOException. The best way, usually, is to make your own method throw the IOException as well, and let the UI deal with them.

Comment: It depends on the code which you didn't post, also who will check that value if it's wrong or good if it documented or not. But if you rethrow the exception caught it will be clear.

Comment: @nikpon : In my code assume that I have `readNum()` method that does reading operation from file using `FileInputStream` and returns the num value(intger). This method is called by some other class. Okay so now if file does not exist I can return -1 or 0 on `FileNotFoundException` to indicate that file does not exist but my question is that what should I return on `IOException` to indicate that this has happened because of that.

Comment: @JB Nizet : Well Thanks for your suggestions. I should refer java doc.

Comment: @Winn: don't return -1 or 0. Let your method throw an IOException, and let the caller (the UI) catch this IOException and display an error message.

Comment: @JB Nizet: Oh ya, that one is better idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**What is an `IOException`**

An `IOException` is any unexpected problem the JVM encounters while attempting to run a program. Possible problems that it may encounter are:

- attempting to read from a file that does not exist
- attempting to write to a file
  that has an invalid name (a slash or a question mark in the title
  should do it)
- attempting to read the next token in a file when there
  are no more tokens.

When an `IOException` is thrown, it means that whatever is throwing the exception (perhaps a `try{}-catch` block that reads data from a file) can throw an `IOException`, for example if the file is not found, corrupted, etc, or when the file is otherwise unable to be read, or any other of a list of issues that can occur with the `IO` package and it's extensions.

**What to do when you encounter an `IOException`?**

When you encounter the `IOException`, you could log it or print an error message. If you are reading from a file that does not exit, you could create one to avoid future exceptions. A lot depends on what you are doing. If you are debugging, printing the stacktrace is always helpful.

Refer to the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following things:

1. **Log the Exception information** on a log file. You can use the following method to populate the Exception information.
2. Try to close the InputStream/OutputStream if it is not null when the IOECeption happens in reading / writing.
3. Throw an Exception of your own **with meaningful message** to let user know what happens.

Answer (score 0):

It is usually when file doesn't exist or you don't have the privileges to read/write.. etc..

Could be other things of course, so the best thing you can do, is [printing the message](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getMessage%28%29) and see what caused the exception. Furthermore, you can see on each class, what methods throws what and when, I advise you to investigate that, it might help you to cover more cases on which you might face this exception.

What should you do when you have an exception? It's up to you an your program, no specific answer for that, depends on many things.

Comment: It is never because 'you don't have enough memory to write to a file'. You don't need additional memory to write to a file. All the memory you need is already allocated at the moment you write.

Comment: Actually, calling a method could (and often will) cause some memory allocation. But if there's not enough memory, an OutOfMemoryError will be thrown. Not an IOException.

Comment: @JBNizet You're right, thanks for the correction.